# Netbeans runs Java but shows no output

Tags: java, netbeans

This is a starting Java program, the classical "hello world", in Netbeans (operation system is Mac). After I clicked on "run" button, the program did run but refused to show the output. What can I do to solve this problem?

[image]

PS: here's the Java version on my Mac:
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And please take time to configure your header ;)

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you are using the wrong method for the output. Try

```
System.out.println("hello world");
```

instead.

The [println method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) you are using does the following:

> Prints a message to the current JDBC log stream.

Which is not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hello world"); // use  System.out.println instead of using println
    }
```